# Increment and update specific value from api list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, upload, increment

So I'm using flutter in Android studio. I generated a list to show some values from am api that has data of things in a vending machine. 'Quantity' is how much of a item there is in the machine. When i set the state to increment a specific item in the list, the count for the single is increased or decreased for all the items not allowing me to update a single item. What i want to do is update the value for the quantity for a specific item only and save that data to the api. I did not set image like below

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will have to set different values for those different items in a map file

like in your screenshot, you have doritoz, tortilas, etc etc
the action for clicking the button should be "doritozValue++" or "doritozValue--"
i don't think you can use a single value for the entire list

this is like working with a dropdown, if you want to set your list dinamicaly, you need not to have a quantity value var, you need to have a list of those vars, and you can access in your dinamically list by making a for, and accessing the determined quantity by: listQuantity[i], that is the determined quantity var for this determined object in the i position